# Admin Page in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, field, models

I want to check about some field in Django if the DB Contains the same value for it before make ADDITION in the admin page . and if there is any field with the same value a message will be appear, then the admin will take a decision if he wants to add or not.
and i dont want to make these field UNIQUE.
is it possible?

Comment: I tried to check the DB if the value entered by the user is already stored or not in all situation a message will appear and the user can take decision before adding

Comment: Ok, so what's the specific problem you're experiencing?